# XAMPP with SkyDrive

Tags: windows, php, xampp, onedrive

Is it possible to shadow my PHP project under development in SkyDrive hosted under XAMPP while keeping the folder in `c:\xampp\www` directory. This way I can share a small-enterprise level project with my peers without making it open (like CodePlex and github offerings for free users).

Comment: What about Dropbox or other similar programs? What about GitHub's paid account? (It's damn cheap, and there is no size limit!)

Comment: What about SkyDrive? If I can do it natively for free, then why should I go for third party solution?

Comment: NTFS junction or something like that? (I hate skydrive, your files are basically public if you upload something there.)

Comment: @shiki, are you trolling here really? Anyway that's not the truth; only shared files/folders are publicly accessible! I am using SkyDrive and I am quite satisfied.

Comment: No I'm not "trolling". They don't encrypt, and basically what you upload, belongs to them. In fact, I just posted an answer, as a comment. See Vulcan's answer down there. Meh.

Comment: That's what they used to say about Google Drive's TOC. SkyDrive's TOC suggests "everything belongs to you stay yours". Its exactly what GoogleDrive and DropBox propose. Secondly, if the files/folder are private, unshared and restricted using access control, how can you call it "public"? Again confusing *unencrypted-private* asset with *public*...

Comment: It's not encrypted at all. That says it all.

Comment: Other people. Data loss, if the account/system gets hacker or breached. Microsoft. Government. | Wuala or OakSpider provides the same 99.9% availability, with AES-256 encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. We can create a `junction` or `symbolic link` in Windows using the command:

```
mklink /d C:\xampp\www\skydrive C:\Users\<your-username>\SkyDrive\myPHPwork
```

Place your project(s) in myPHPwork folder. Then you can browse to:

```
iexplore http://127.0.0.1/skydrive/some/path.php
```

[Here](http://skydrivedev.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/using-wamp-with-skydrive/) is a great article explaining the exact scenario using [wamp](/questions/tagged/wamp).